# De-Activate a Process Builder via Metadata API

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, jenkins

I want to de-activate a process builder on a destination sandbox. I have set the status as Obsolete on the .flow file and deploy via Jenkins. But it didn't get deactivated. API Version is 52. Any idea? Will that going to be a manual step? I added the flowdefinition and made the version as 0 too

Comment: Did you try to deploy it without flowdefinition and version number? I believe that this it the issue

Comment: Yes, it didn't work with Status being set to Obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can deactivate a Process Builder by *only* deploying the `FlowDefinition` and setting `activeVersionNumber` to 0.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeVersionNumber>0</activeVersionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>
```

But, I'd recommend not using [FlowDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm) as suggested in the docs

> In API version 44.0, we recommend upgrading your flows to flow
> metadata file names without version numbers and discontinue using the
> FlowDefinition object to activate or deactivate a flow. Then use the
> Flow object to activate or deactivate a flow

The issue will be that this leaves you with a manual process for your given scenario. Hopefully, it would be a small use case where you deactivate an active flow (and that's the only action taken). The more common use case, deploying a new active version, is supported with the `Flow` metadata assuming you turn on [Deploy processes and flows as active](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_deploy_as_active.htm&type=5&release=216) within `Process Automation Settings`

You may think doing this manually is too painful but, for source control purposes, `FlowDefinition` can be confusing as it refers to version numbers that are no longer utilized [since API 44](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fullname.htm&type=5&release=216) and could lead to incorrect changes as there's no guarantee the # of versions in one org matches with another depending on your pipeline/CI.

I would recommend upvoting the idea to [Activate/Deactivate flows via Metadata API](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DhHjAAK) that is still open. Even though the documentation seems confusing as it seems to hint the `status` on `Flow` should work, it's easy to test that you cannot deactivate a flow/PB and can only deploy new versions (as active) that can deactivate a previous version. Deploying draft Flow metadata to an org that has the given metadata activated will simply create a new version of that PB that is inactive (and leave the active version as is).